Task Scheduler not running task when I am logged out?
I have an .exe that uses Python script I wrote to open a Selenium browser, log into a site, download a .xml file, and then sign out of the site and close the browser. I want to schedule this to happen every 24 hours. The script works and I can run it through Task Scheduler. I have run with highest privileges checked, and am running the task as a member of Administrators.
My problem is, I can not get Task Scheduler to run this task when I'm logged out. It runs on schedule when I'm logged in or when I manually run the task. But if I log out, the task does not run on schedule. It also shows no history of being started and failing when logged out. It simply does not "exist" when logged out.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance. Screen grab below shows settings.


For my scheduled tasks that run like you want, I have them set to "Run whether user is logged on or not," which requires you to "use the following user account" of an actual user, not a group like Administrators as shown in the screenshot. So I would try changing Administrators to a user.

Anytime I use a setting other than Administrators, I am unable to run the task with "Run whether user is logged on or not" selected. The history shows the task is Run, but it never runs. I know it's not interactive with this setting so I won't "see" the task running, but the task never creates the file that it should, and I'm not seeing any errors in the scripts error log, so I assume the task is not actually running. If I run the task manually, the task "runs" for about 5 seconds and then finishes with no created file (the desired output of the script ran by the task).
